# Name of a newly defined view controller is updated to a new name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using XCode 7.1 beta version.
Whenever I define a new view controller for eg. with name "rootViewController", the name is changed to "UIViewController+rootViewController" in the IDE.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be creating a category on `UIViewController`. While creating new file please ensure you do not select category as type.

Comment: That totally depends on your need. Use `Cocoa Touch Class` file and choose your language. I would also advise to read Apple docs on this.